# "forbidden for me" vs "forbidden to me"?

Tags: prepositions

I have a doubt how to use the word "forbidden" with which preposition. For example:

"Fats are forbidden **for / to** me because I am athlete"

"Is it forbidden **for / to** you as a religious?"

Comment: It's worth noting that you don't actually *need* any preposition at all - *Fats [are **forbidden me** because](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22are+forbidden+me+because%22) I am athlete* is syntactically valid (but it's maybe a little bit "formal").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple common usage is

> forbidden **for** +*noun*
>   *It is forbidden **for** me to smoke.*
>
> forbidden **to** +*verb*
>   *It is forbidden **to** smoke.*